# Error when accessing specific ADT

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I am defining a type and everything works fine except the method that accesses the last data constructor : `JArray`

I get the following error:

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class `JArray'
    A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?

   |
28 |     getArray::JValue->Maybe JArray
   |
```

Why is this happening? I can load the module and instantiate the `JArray` but it won't load with the `getArray` method.

```
data JValue = JString String
            | JNumber Double
            | JBool Bool
            | JNull
            | JObject [(String, JValue)]
            | JArray [JValue]
            deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

getString :: JValue -> Maybe String
getString (JString s) = Just s
getString _ = Nothing

getInt :: JValue -> Maybe Int
getInt (JNumber n) = Just (truncate n)
getInt _ = Nothing

getBool :: JValue -> Maybe Bool
getBool (JBool b) = Just b
getBool _ = Nothing

getObject (JObject obj) = Just obj
getObject _ = Nothing

--What is wrong in this method?

getArray :: JValue -> Maybe JArray    
getArray (JArray arr) = Just arr
getArray _ = Nothing
```

Comment: `JArray` is not a type, it's a constructor. What are you trying to do here? Did you mean to write `getArray :: JValue -> Maybe [JValue]`? That's the type of the function here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`JArray` is a value constructor, not a type. You cannot use `JArray` in type signatures.*** This is actually explained in the error: `` Not in scope: type constructor or class `JArray' ``.

Since we see this:

```
data JValue = JString String
            | JNumber Double
            | JBool Bool
            | JNull
            | JObject [(String,JValue)]
            | JArray [JValue]           -- This line defines JArray
```

So `JArray :: [JValue] -> JValue`. Looking at your function, but ignoring the erroneous type signature:

```
getArray (JArray arr) = Just arr
-- ^ arr :: [JValue], so Just arr :: Maybe [JValue]
getArray _ = Nothing
-- ^ Nothing :: Maybe a
```

So, since you're pattern matching on some `JValue`, the function has type `getArray :: JValue -> Maybe [JValue]`. This is because types and inhabitants of that type are distinct.

---

** except with `DataKinds`, but this is a separate concern.*